# Alice knows a+b, Bob knows a×b. Can we find (a,b)?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, meta-knowledge

There are two distinct positive integers $a,b$ (i.e. $a\neq b$) such that $a < 7$ and $b < 7$.

Alice has been told the sum of $a$ and $b$. Bob has been told the product of $a$ and $b$.

Both Alice and Bob are aware of all the information mentioned above.

This is their conversation:

> Alice says, "I am not sure if you know the sum that I have been told."

> Bob says, "Actually, even before you spoke, I knew the sum that was told to you."

What are the possible values of $a$ and $b$ ?

Inspired by a Ted-ed video that I saw.

Comment: I think one can go one small step further. Alice and Bob now know the exact values of $a$ and $b$. Soppose it was Ximena who had told sum and product of the (different) values $a$ and $b$ to Alice and Bob respectively. She tells the entire story to You (say: you are Yves or Yvette) and adds: if You would know the value of the difference between $a$ and $b$,I am sure you would know the unique values for $a$ and $b$. What are these values?

Comment: @OP we can assume Alice and Bob reason perfectly, right? So Alice could as well have said "I don't know if you know the sum that I have been told.". Right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @OP would you mind, for reference, provide Ted-ed video URL

Comment: @FirstNameLastName , this is the ted ed puzzle. https://youtu.be/iNgJCYPdmdQ?si=zf3JXBDr8cyxBA_X  the statement,  " I don't know if you know the sum that I have been told." is the same as the statement, "I am not sure if you know the sum that I have been told."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the solution is

> that the possible values of $(a,b)$ are $(1,4), (2,5), (3,5)$ (or swapping their orders).

First, we narrow down the solution space by observing that after Alice's statement

> the only possible sums are $5, 7$ or $8$.

Then among these candidates, only the above solutions satisfy Bob's statement.

Detailed method

> The following tables lists sums and the possible products corresponding to each sum. The starred products indicate that they appear in more than one row.
>
> ```
>  sum=3: 2
>  sum=4: 3
>  sum=5: 4, 6*
>  sum=6: 5, 8
>  sum=7: 6*, 10, 12*
>  sum=8: 12*, 15
>  sum=9: 18, 20
>  sum=10: 24
>  sum=11: 30
> ```

> We see that the only rows with a mixture of starred and nonstarred products are 5, 7, 8, which Alice observes. Within these rows, if Bob observes a non-starred product, then he may logically make his statement.